# Reading file to disk error, "name and value are required for setHeader()"

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, http-headers, mean-stack

Trying to allow users to upload image files to the Node.js server in a MEAN Stack application. I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) for the client side angular directive. That seems to be working good enough. I run into an error when I pass the image to the server.

I use an API route to handle the work on the server side. The server will be responsible for saving the file to disk with [node-multiparty](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) module. It seems to hit route but when it tries to emit a close event I get the error. **throw new Error('"name" and "value" are required for setHeader().'**

The file I want is in my temp folder but it doesn't get saved to the target directory on my server plus I get the header error after the file should have been saved. So I need to stop the error and save the file with `fs.rename()` to the target image directory.

Here is the code that is breaking.

file api.js

```
// router to save images
router.route('/img/upload')

.post(function (req, res) {
console.log("image upload hits the router")

var options = {};
var count = 0;
var form = new multiparty.Form(options);

//save file to disk
form.on('file', function (name, file) {
var uploadDirectory = 'img/user/profile/';
var oldPath = file.path;
var newPath = uploadDirectory + file.originalFilename;

fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('renamed complete');
});
});

// Close emitted after form parsed
form.on('close', function () {
console.log('Upload completed!');
res.setHeader('text/plain'); // Here is the line that gives an error.
res.end('Received ' + count + ' files');
});

// Parse req
form.parse(req);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I got to work for me

The actual line that gave me an error was `setHeaders`. It appears I needed to put the name and value as strings separated by a comma. This works perfectly for me now. I hope it saves everyone time coding.

```
// post 
.post(function (req, res) {

var options = {};
var count = 0;
var form = new multiparty.Form(options);

form.on('error', function (err) {
console.log('Error parsing form: ' + err.stack);
});

//save file to disk
form.on('file', function (name, file) {
var uploadDirectory = '/img/user/profile/';
var oldPath = file.path;
var newPath = uploadDirectory + file.originalFilename;

fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('renamed complete');
});
});

// Close emitted after form parsed
form.on('close', function () {
console.log('Upload completed!');
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.end('Received ' + count + ' files');
});

// Parse req
form.parse(req);

});
```